# Call click event of a button form another website

Tags: asp.net, click, onclick, buttonclick

I am explaing with a exmple what I am trying to do.

Suppose there is a site abc.com and i am working for site xyz.com

in a aspx page of xyz.com i want to have the results of a aspx page of www.abc.com/somepage.aspx  conatins a textbox , a combobox a option button and a submit button i want to fill this form and want to click the submit button then to save the details in a file but i want to perfom this action on xyz.com/somepage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting is XSS. This is usually undesired. Basically, you are looking for ways to bypass the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). A lot of browsers will block whatever you are doing. Imagine if there was an online poll on another site I wanted to stuff. If it was possible for me to silently interact with the other site while visitors are using my site, I would be doing what you want to do. I can't do it though, because there are a lot of blocks against that by browsers and web developers.

Edit: You might be able to do this nowadays if you implement CORS. But it’s on the target site to allow that. Most browsers now support it since the time I've originally answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could host a page on the xyz site and use an iframe to display that form on the abc site.  That's probably the simplest approach.  Otherwise this is a perfect scenario to use some sort of web service.

Comment: No in this case i do not host the xyz site its of any other person a third party.

Comment: its a kind of govt site to fill itr returns etc. form my web application